# Hide an empty line through Python IF statement in FME Workbench

Tags: python, fme-form, line, address

I am trying to set a rule that would move up filled lines and hide an empty line (it can be on any line) in a postal address through PythonCaller transformer. I have a database table consisted of address elements (organisation_name, department_name, house_name, house_number, street_name, specific_locality, town, post_code…) and these elements are somehow ordered on address lines.

Here is an example:

```
house_name
house_number, street_name

town
post_code
```

What I need to do now is to hide the empty line in the middle (address_line_3) by moving the last two address lines up (town_line and post_code_line).

So it's going to look like this:

```
house_name
house_number, street_name
town
post_code
```

The order of the address elements varies as well as occurrence of the empty lines. Because I am a beginner in Python I can only guess how to do it. If there is any other transformer in FME Workbench I can use, I welcome your ideas.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544921/best-method-for-reading-newline-delimited-files-in-python-and-discarding-the-new) may be of use. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding '**Tester**' and '**AttributeCreator**' transformers instead of coding it in '**PythonCaller**' transformer. In the **Tester** I selected 'line3' as a left value (transformers must be connected to see the attributes set previously) and empty string as a right value. In the **AttributeCreator** I set the lines in order and I added a NULL value for 'line5'.